# Windows Service Password not saved

Tags: windows, windows-services

I have a windows service working on a domain service account.  The service do not remember the password for more then a day.  I have set the service to restart automatically on a fail once since we have some db connections issues that cause the service to break every now and again.

My problem is that the service do not remember the password and I need to set the password each time the service has stopped.

The server is windows server 2012 R2 standard and is a VM.  Does anyone know what I can try to have the server remember the password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a case of the [group policy overwriting the local policy](http://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/windows-services/windows-service-forgets-password/).

Comment: Sorry for my late response, had to schedule these changes for the server restart.  This did not work, I still require to retype the password after a day.

Comment: I believe it had to be a group policy.  Suddenly it started working and the IT department does not inform me of what they did